# How do I do a "like" wildcard comparison in Entity Framework in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 RC for .NET 4.0 and I'm trying to figure out how to do a wildcard comparison with Entity Framework.

I'd like to have the following query for EF where I find all the names that start with 'J'

```
select * from Users where FirstName like 'J%'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from user in Users where user.FirstName.StartsWith("J") select user;
```

Comment: @David you're missing the needed `select user` at the end for query expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var query = Users.Where(user => user.FirstName.StartsWith("J"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework), I assume it hasn't changed in .net 4.0