# How to create like '234%4' or %2324%335% in EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008

Anyone know how to do this query? I know I can usar a start with  and EndWith, but I have to parse the string and I can have %2324%335% and now? Any way to do this easy?

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework suggest that LIKE is not supported in EF. However this post is from back when EF1 was the current, so EF4 may be  different in this respect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [create a custom function](http://jendaperl.blogspot.com/2011/02/like-in-linq-to-entities.html):

```
    <Function Name="String_Like" ReturnType="Edm.Boolean">
      <Parameter Name="searchingIn" Type="Edm.String" />
      <Parameter Name="lookingFor" Type="Edm.String" />
      <DefiningExpression>
        searchingIn LIKE lookingFor
      </DefiningExpression>
    </Function>
```

And call it using

```
[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunction( "Your.Namespace", "String_Like")]
public static Boolean Like(this String searchingIn, String lookingFor) {
    throw new Exception("Not implemented");
}
```

Comment: Use the `Like` extension method in a query; see http://jendaperl.blogspot.com/2011/02/like-in-linq-to-entities.html.  Note that I haven't tried this.

Comment: I get this error: Error 507 Namespace prefix 'ef4ex' is not defined.

Comment: @Jedi: Get rid of them; they shouldn't have been there.

Comment: Now I get this: {"The specified method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' on the type 'LCP.RM.Dal.EntityFramework.Design.HelperMethods' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression."}

Comment: Awesome! Putting the Like-Function into a static class with name abc works great and then you need to call it on a property of type string inside the where function with LINQ! This solves many problems we had by using SQLQuery to archieve using LIKE on a odata/entitfy framework wcf data service.

Answer (score 2):

```
where entity.field.Contains("2324") && entity.field.Contains("335")
```

Comment: this wouldn't work if the first string contains the second string

Comment: @Aducci: what do you mean? give an example.