# Does EdmFunction work in EF4.3 code-first (no edmx model)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3

ref: [How to create like '234%4' or %2324%335% in EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891165/how-to-create-like-2344-or-2324335-in-entityframework?answertab=active#tab-top)

Does the solution using [EdmFunction] work for esql + EF4.3 code-first  (where there is no .edmx file) by simply implementing the function?  then would it be available in esql, ie: "it.UserName.Like('_user%')" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `EdmFunction` attribute and its functionality is currently dependent on EDMX mapping file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i wonder if there's any other equivalent functionality with code-first approach.. `[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunction( "Your.Namespace", "String_Like")]public static Boolean Like(this String searchingIn, String lookingFor) { throw new Exception("Not implemented"); }` maybe this is the function that query builder calls onto so if i implement it instead of throwing the exception ... ?

Comment: No. There is no equivalent. The function is only stub for SQL function mapped in EDMX file. Implementing it will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Then, as now, you can use `.StartsWith` or `.Contains` which map to LIKE:

```
it.UserName.StartsWith("_user")
```

will translate to

```
UserName LIKE '_user%'
```

(and secretly apply your case insensitive collations and such, causing Contains to deviate from an accurate mapping to the local functionality.)