# StartsWith in Expression return null

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could somone tell me why this statement return nothing and how to correct it. What im trying todo is select User where username starts with the letter from the alphabet

alpha = "A" "B" "C" "D" etc.
both don't work

```
IList<MembershipUser> users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
.Where(x => x.UserName.StartsWith(alpha) == true).ToList();

IList<MembershipUser> users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
.Where(x => x.UserName.StartsWith(alpha)).ToList();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Like Operator in Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework). I'd imagine it should work similar in your environment.

Comment: what does `Membership.GetAllUsers()` return?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper - [Membership.GetAllUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx) returns a [System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipusercollection.aspx).

Comment: Get All users return a collection of MembershipUser

Comment: Then why do we need a `Cast<MembershipUser>()` here?

Comment: First, I'm assuming `Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()` isn't null. Second, `StartsWith` is case sensitive - have you tried using `x.UserName.ToLower().StartsWith(alpha.ToLower())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use this

```
IList<MembershipUser> users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
.Where(x => x.UserName.StartsWith(alpha, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is actually better than simons so i'll mark this as answered because it is better

Answer (score 3):

`StartsWith` is case sensitive

Use `x.UserName.ToLower().StartsWith(alpha.ToLower())`