# How to implement the sql "%" in EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

What I want to do is :

```
var TheQuery = db.Conventions.Where(p => p.Categories.Contains("%"));
```

but it nothing is returned from database!

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework

Comment: That query should return all rows that have a `%` in them. Could you explain your use case a little better if that's not what you're expecting...?

Comment: are you trying to find conventions with the '%' character somewhere in their Category field?

Comment: Do you want to search for the category named "%" or for any category (e.g. SELECT * FROM CATS WHERE CATS.NAME LIKE %). In the latter case you can use p.Categories.Any()

Comment: I have a search form with multiple fields, what i want to do is what to assigne to variable if it's an empty string.   `if(Request["Categorie"]!="") categorie = Request["Categorie"]; else' categorie = "%"; //select all categories var TheQuery = db.Conventions.Where(p => p.Categories.intituleCategorie.Contains(categorie) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to DaveShaw I think this is what you should do:

```
IQueryable<Convention> query = db.Conventions;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputCategory))
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.Categories.Contains(inputCategory));
}
if (!string.InNullOrWhiteSpace(inputName))
{
    query = query.Where(p=> p.Name == inputName);
}
```

etc.

Now if you want to make sure that your Convention has at least one category, you can instead use .Any()

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputCategory))
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.Categories.Any());
}
```

or if it should have any category with a specific name

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputCategory))
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.Categories.Any(c => c.Name.Contains(inputCategory));
}
```

The actual query isn't executed until you call ToArray, ToList or ToEnumerable on it (or any other method that requires client side evaluation). As long as you stick to pure LINQ calls on the Query object, you can continue to stick where clauses to it until you're satisfied.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do that for multiple fields (24 other fields)

Comment: So add 24 if's. it's better than sending an overly complex query to the database.

Comment: Please notice (from my practice) .Any() generate a huge db request. Be careful with it.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL "%"? Do you mean when using with a LIKE? If so just use `.Contains("Products")` to bring back Categories such as:

```
carProducts
houseProducts2
```

i.e. The contains will bring back results where the Categories property/field "contains" the string, regardless of what is either side of it.

Or did you mean you would like the Categories to contain the character '%'? (You are successfully doing that now)