# How to search through Database with entity that matches to part of the string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know `Where()` searches through my database for anything that matches and returns me a list, however it matches whole words. How do you search through the database and find everything without matching whole words?

For example, the user wants to search for: *funny*

then my search function will return anything that has the word "funny" in it, such as

- funnygirls
- funnydogs
- funnypeople
- funnybikes; etc...

I implemented the `Where()`, but it doesn't do the feature above? Is there any fixes? or any Alternatives?

Edit:

Context Code:

> ```
>    public static List<PhotoAlbumDto> searchAlbumsFromDA(string inputName)
>    {
>        EzPrintsEntities db = new EzPrintsEntities();
>        List<PhotoAlbum> albums = new List<PhotoAlbum>();
>        albums = db.PhotoAlbums.Where(b => b.NAME == inputName).ToList();
>    }
> ```

This returns me only things that match "funny" EXACTLY... so in other words, I can't search up everything that only has the word "funny" in it, such as funnycats... Only "funny" will be returned, and nothing else.

Comment: Post code samples, it's hard do tell what you've tried from free form descriptions.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a pretty straight-forward question, but here's the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
albums = db.PhotoAlbums.Where(b => b.NAME.Contains("funny")).ToList();
```