# How to write a dynamic where 'like' query in Entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Here is my code:

```
//order my baselist is context.Entity 
public static GridData Getdata<T>(ObjectSet<T> baseList,
    int currentPage,
    int rowsPerPage,
    string sortcolumn,
    string sortord,
    string searchQuery,
    string searchColumns)where T: class{
var query = baseList.OrderBy("it." + sortcolumn + " " + sortord);
        string strPredicate = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchColumns))
        {
            strPredicate = "it." + searchColumns + " LIKE   @" + searchColumns + "  ";

            query = baseList.Where(strPredicate, new ObjectParameter(searchColumns, searchQuery)).OrderBy("it." + sortcolumn + " " + sortord);
        }
}
```

My problem is i am trying to write down or form a like query in entity framework and seems like it does not support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  use this

```
 query = baseList.Where(baseli=>baseli.Contains(searchColumns )).OrderBy("it." + sortcolumn + " " + sortord);
```

:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033024/337294) which is the `LIKE` operator equivalent in entity framework.