# Finding items from a list in an array stored in a DB field

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a legacy database that has data elements stored as a comma delimited list in a single database field. (I didn't design that, I'm just stuck with it.)

I have a list of strings that I would like to match to any of the individual values in the "array" in the DB field and am not sure how to do this in Linq.

My list:

```
List<string> items= new List<string>();
items.Add("Item1");  
items.Add("Item2");
```

The DB field "Products" would contain data something like:

```
"Item1,Item3,Item4"
"Item3,Item5,Item6"
"Item2,Item7,Item6"
"Item1,Item2"
"Item1"
```

My first pass at the Linq query was:

```
var results = (from o in Order
.Where(p=> items.Contains(p.Products)
```

But I know that won't work. because it will only return the records that contain only "Item1" or "Item2". So with the example data above it would return 0 records. I need to have it return two records.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple clever trick for searching comma-separated lists.  First, add an extra `,` to the beginning and end of the target value (the product list), and the search value.  Then search for that exact string.  So for example, you would search `,Item1,Item3,Item4,` for `,Item1,`.  The purpose of this is to prevent false positives, i.e., `Item12,Item3` finding a match for `Item1`, while allowing items at the beginning/end of the list to be properly found.

Then, you can use the LINQ `.Any` method to check that any item in your list is a match to the product list, like the following:

```
var results = (from o in Order
    .Where(o => items.Any(i => (","+o.Products+",").Contains(","+i+",")))
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're allowed to do `String.Contains` in Entity Framework?

Comment: @IronMan84: I don't really know a lot about EF (I use mostly LINQ-to-SQL), but I know `String.Contains` is pretty easy to express in SQL (e.g., `LIKE` clause), so I'd be quite surprised if it wasn't supported.  [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework#comment2470199_1033024) seems to indicate that it is allowed.

Comment: Using your suggestion I am running into an issue when the item is not the first "string" in the DB array. i.e. If I selected on item3 in the example above I would get record 2  but not 1

Comment: @JohnS: Please double-check you've implemented the logic correctly.  There is a comma before and after both the `Products` value and the item.  I tested it and it seems to work fine: http://ideone.com/aOFcom.  Can you show your current working code?

Comment: I apologize. The data I had used for an example above didn't have the spaces in it like the live data did.  I have added a o.Products.Replace(" ","") to the code and it works correctly.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to parse the list in the `Products` field:

```
var results = (from o in Order
    .Where(o => items.Any(i => o.Products.Split(',').Contains(i))
```

But that would parse the string multiple times for each record.  You could try pulling back ALL of the records, parsing each record once, then doing the comparison:

```
var results = from o in Order
              let prods = o.Products.Split(',')
              where items.Any(i => prods.Contains(i))
              select o;
```