# SQL expressions in EF using Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I would like to know if something similar to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx) (linq to SQL)

```
customers.Where(c => SqlMethods.Like(c.Name, "%john%"));
```

is possible to do in Entity Framework. Preferably using lamba expressions.

My goal is to do something like this:

```
string searchString1 = "%foo";
string searchString2 = "%foo%";
string searchString3 = "foo";

customers.Where(c => SqlMethods.Like(c.Name, searchStringX));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4935438/743382 may be a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Custumers.where(c=>c.name.contains("foo"))

u can try this it will work 100%

Comment: And how would it handle `searchString1`? Would it still do a contains or do I get an `EndsWith()` behaviour?

Comment: ucan use ends with also like customers.where(a=>a.name.endswith(""))

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything new in lambda expressions but you could write a linq query like this:

```
var result = from i in customers 
         where i.name.Contains("yourString") 
         select i;
```

**Also the datatype of the column should be varchar**

Update: Just figured it out with lambda expressions

```
var result = customers.Where(c => c.name.StartsWith("yourString"));
var result = customers.Where(c => c.name.EndsWith("yourString"));
var result = customers.Where(c => c.name.Contains("yourString"));
```

Comment: And how would it handle `searchString1`? Would it still do a contains or do I get an `EndsWith()` behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string contains, starts with and ends with methods to do the same thing:

```
string searchString1 = "foo"

var customerList = from x in customers where x.Name.Contains(searchString1) select x;

 var customerList = from x in customers where x.Name.StartsWith(searchString1) select x;

 var customerList = from x in customers where x.Name.EndsWith(searchString1) select x;
```

Comment: This isn't very dynamic... :/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
.Where(c => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%John", c.Name) > 0);
```