# Getting Records On The Bases Of Range(would be char,would be int)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have some different scenario. Roomname column of varchar datatype. I want to get records on the bases of room range:
Like: If I am entering A To Z Range of records then I need to get records between roomname A,B,C...Z

If I will Enter Room range R1 to R30 Will get all records between R1 to R30

How can I do this

Answer (score 1):

See this answer:

[Like Operator in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework)

You should be able to use that method to narrow down your record results to at least the letter component of your room range. From there a little VB will get you the rest of the way.

```
'I assume:
'results() is a string array of room numbers formatted like "R1" or "R30"
'rangeStart and rangeEnd are corresponding integers, e.g. 1 and 30

For Each roomName As String In results
    Dim roomNum As Integer = CInt(Mid(roomName, 2))
        If roomNum > rangeStart And roomNum < rangeEnd Then
            'Your code here
        End If
Next room
```

Comment: How your integer parameters will works in entityframework? And If I  Want to display result A to P How like operator will work here could you please explain?

Comment: The above code does not involve passing any integer parameters to/from entity framework; only strings. For a range with the Like Operator, use [A-P]*. (The PatIndex documentation doesn't define acceptable patterns, so I assume it uses the same format as Like, but am unable to test at this time.) So something `Dim Pattern As String = "[" & Left(roomStart, 1) & "-" & Left(roomEnd, 1)`, where roomStart and roomEnd are strings like "A1" and "P30". Allowing a range of letters also means a more sophisticated If test to make sure the room is in range for searches such as A30-B1.

Comment: I hope this helps. It's hard to clarify further without knowing your code and table structure.