# C# LINQ how to check if variable starts with "M####" where # is numeric

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm making a changelog web application that is linked to GitLab, that gets data from a database table that is updated whenever there's a push on GitLab.

To make a push we add a custom ID to the message area followed by the message that could be whatever. This custom ID must be; M####/C#####/Merge/Revert. Where # represents a numeric value (0-9).

The application has to recognise every push's ID so that it can be later used for filtering etc.

Previously I've used this code to select only the M#### and C#####, but once 'Merge' was used as the ID it would also show up.

```
var query = from c in db.Clgcom
    where c.Prjid == 7
    && (c.Modid.StartsWith("C")
    || c.Modid.StartsWith("M"))
    select c.Modid;
```

result:

```
M1234, M2345, C12345, M0000, C75843, Merge
```

Using `.StartsWith("M####")` doesn't work, and I've got no idea how to solve this other than using 10 different cases;

```
where c.Modid.StartsWith("M0")
|| c.Modid.StartsWith("M1")
|| c.Modid.StartsWith("M2")
|| c.Modid.StartsWith("M3")
// etc.
```

Is there a better way to solve my problem?

**edit:** I'm using Entity Framework so regex could cause problems.

Comment: Is this Linq 2 Objects or Linq 2 SQL or Entity Framework or similar, that is, which one is it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Entity Framework

Comment: Then stay with the 10 cases. Bad design fosters bad solutions, or you can drop that part of the query on the database-side, convert the end-result (unfiltered) to a list or `IEnumerable<T>`, then do normal Linq 2 objects to handle this part. Neither is ideal.

Comment: You could also define a UDF in your database which uses the PATTERN functionality in SQL Server and then import it into your EF Model as a composble function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If targetting SQL Server, [SqlFunctions.PatIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used. Unlike the EF mapping of `string.Contains`, PatIndex supports LIKE syntax.

> Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a *[LIKE] pattern* in a specified expression..

A value of 1 means "matched at the first character".

```
var query = from c in db.Clgcom
    where c.Prjid == 7
      && SqlFunctions.PatIndex("M[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", c.Modid) == 1
    select c.Modid;
```

As with LIKE, SQL Server is capable of leveraging indexing with PatIndex - in this case a direct seek (if applicable) prior to any other checking because of the fixed anchored "M" start. Actual plan selection may vary.

Another option is to pull it client-side and use Linq 2 Objects with a regular expression or whatnot. This can still be done with little performance impact if there are a low percent of 'edge cases' because the original query be restricted so that most of the work is done in SQL where appropriate indexes can be applied.

```
var query = (from c in db.Clgcom
    where c.Prjid == 7
      && c.Modid.StartsWith("M") // .. LIKE "M%"
    select c.Modid)
    .ToList(); // -> IList<string>, in L2O land

// I'm a fan of this syntax :}
var re = new Regex(@"^M\d{4}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var finalClientFilter = query
    .Where(s => re.IsMatch(s));
```

---

See [Like Operator in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1033007/2864740) for general hullaballo.

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that the domain of `Modid` values is exactly as you set-out in your original question then you can simply check for unwanted *known values* which, by elimination, means the remainder will match `M...` and `C...`, and the query will be fast and efficient if you use an index (`StartsWith` is fairly cheap in databases)

```
IQueryable<String> query = db.Clgcom
    .Where( c =>
        c.Prjid == 7
        &&
        c.Modid != "Merge"
        &&
        ( 
            c.Modid.StartsWith("M") || c.Modid.StartsWith("C")
        )
    )
    .Select( c => c.Modid );
```

But if you can't make that guarantee then you'll have to use `PATINDEX`, which is exposed to EF as `SqlFunctions.PatIndex`.

Comment: What about `MaskK`? Would also match.

Comment: @HimBromBeere the OP didn't say that would be in the domain of values.