# What is the SQL LIKE operator equivalent in LINQ having multiple % operators in the input text?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

To convert the SQL LIKE query to LINQ which having "%"(percentage) operators both at the start and end of the string, we use the `Contains()` method.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username LIKE '%test%'
```

The equivalent LINQ is:

```
var users = (from usr in Context.Users
            where usr.Username.Contains("test")
            select usr).ToList();
```

What will be equivalent of the below query which contains multiple "%"(percentage) operators in the input text?

```
SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username LIKE '%test%email%'
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Note:** The query will be executed in the EntityFramework(version 6.1.3)

Comment: Sounds like a Regex to me.

Comment: You don't mentioned your environment, but for example EF have `Like` function: `entity => EF.Functions.Like(entity.Name, $"%{searchname}%")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Like Operator in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework)

Comment: You'll find your solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442276/797882) at the duplicated link.

Comment: @CodeNotFound DbFunction.Like() worked like charm for EF 6.2.0. However, I noticed the EntityFramework is in version 6.1.3 in the target project. The Like() is not available in "6.1.3". Is there any alternate solution for this? I have updated the note in the original question to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Do all your best to upgrade to 6.2.0. There is no breaking changes. I did it in the past weeks and no modifications needed. Don't forget that EF 6 follows [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posting the comments given by [@Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565525/fabio) and [@CodeNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797882/codenotfound) as answer for reference.

In EntityFramework version **6.2.0**:

```
var users = (from usr in Context.Users
            where DbFunctions.Like(usr.Username, "%test%email%")
            select usr).ToList();
```