# Linq equivalent to '_' in SQL

Tags: c#, linq

is there an equivalent from '**_**' in SQL to Linq.

In SQL it is like a white-space, so it selects everything and ignores this char.

e.g. `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.ID LIKE '12431466_1'`selects all IDs with 12431266 and at the end 1

Comment: Please provide the context by specifying an example SQL query with `'_'` in it.

Comment: Do you mean Linq _in general_ or Linq that is supported by the SQL provider (mean it generates SQL with the `_` wildcard character)?

Comment: That's *not* a whitespace in SQL. It's a single character placeholder in LIKE patterns

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1033007/335858)

Comment: You can simulate this with `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` and `Length` combined, but LINQ to SQL / EF doesn't have direct support for `LIKE` except for certain specific database providers.

Comment: @NetMage I accepted your proposal, it works because I expact just one `_`. In other cases it would be a bigger problem. But thanks a lot.

Comment: A general solution for `_` would involve using `Substring` but would require knowing the position and number of the `_` ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your specific needs:

If you're using linq-to-sql and would like it to run the query you posted, you can use the same string with [SqlMethods.Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like?view=netframework-4.7.2).

If you want to have a solution for linq-to-objects or a custom linq provider, you'll need to either use string methods running inside the C# runtime, like `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` or use [Regext.IsMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.7.2) or something similar.