# Use LIKE "%{%}%" in Entity Framework with Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to do a request to my database and I want to use something like the "LIKE" operator in SQL to resolve this pattern: `%{%}%`
Using the "SQL-friendly" syntax.
Currently my request looks like:

```csharp
var routelist = (from dbHost in db.Hosts
                             where dbHost.Host == host
                             join dbRoute in db.Route on dbHost.HostsId equals dbRoute.HostId
                             select dbRoute).ToList();
```

If someone know how to do, can he tells it to me ? Thanks

**EDIT :**

I want to do something like it :

```csharp
var routelist = (from dbHost in db.Hosts
                             where dbHost.Host == host
                             join dbRoute in db.Route on dbHost.HostsId equals dbRoute.HostId
                             where dbRoute.alias like "%{%}%"
                             select dbRoute).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you searching for wildcards in linq? In that case this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040380/wildcard-search-for-linq

Comment: @Mickey I think this is what I look for but do this way is optimized ?
Do it only filter the request result or do it only pick the corrects fields in the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to perform such LIKE queries with entity framework (and this happens very rarely, because such like queries usually cannot use any index and so perform full table scan and are quite slow on big tables), I use `PATINDEX`, like this:

```
var routelist = (from dbHost in db.Hosts
                         where dbHost.Host == host
                         join dbRoute in db.Route on dbHost.HostsId equals dbRoute.HostId
                         where SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%{%}%",dbRoute.alias) > 0
                         select dbRoute).ToList();
```

`PATINDEX` function in sql server is like LIKE, but returns the position of the first match.

If you want to perform LIKE query in a form of "%something%", you can use Contains("something"). If it has the form of "%something" - use StartsWith("something"). If it has the form of "something%" - use EndsWith("something").

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I need but It also seems not to exist on __ASP.NET Core__
(Actually, System.Data.Object seems not to exists)

Comment: True, didn't notice it's about EF Core. Well such functions are not yet supported there (not sure how it can be used for any serious stuff in current state). You can try workaround using FromSql as described here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3325

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework Core 2.0 has now available `EF.Functions` property that includes `EF.Functions.Like()`.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/

Example:

```
var customers =
    from c in context.Customers
    where EF.Functions.Like(c.Name, "a%");
    select c;
```