# like query in Entity framework 6

Tags: postgresql, linq, entity-framework-6

I have Entity Framework with PostgreSQL 
Now I do something like this:

```
string query = "select * from dbo.Products where name ilike '%test%phrase%' 
                or code ilike '%test%phrase%' or code2 ilike '%test%phrase%'";

var result = context.Products.SqlQuery(query);
```

So I get products with name like this:

test some phrase
some test 
some phrase
and so on.

How to perform same query with linq or other type of query without raw sql?

I need part of phrase from start of string + part from middle, mayby part from end. Something like regular expression. In postgres it can be done with % symbol

Comment: Try this for regex http://buildregex.com/

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040380/wildcard-search-for-linq/42307642#42307642
I do not know if it works for Postgresql as well, but I think it does since it there are equivalent functions like str_pos and position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer was wrong (my apologies to the OP.)

You can do Name.StartsWith, Name.EndsWith, or Name.Contains.

On top of that you can use Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.PgSqlFunctions to achieve LIKE comparisons. i.e.

```
where PgSqlFunctions.Like(PgSqlFunctions.Lower(c.Name), PgSqlFunctions.Lower(pattern))
```

Regards,

AB

PS: If you have a lot of data that needs searching like that check out trigram indexes - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
var result = context.Products.Where(h=>h.Name.Contains("TestPhrase") ||
                                    h.Code.Contains("TestPhrase"))
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: How it works if: Search phrase is **"some%phrase"** and result have to be **"some test phrase"**

Comment: @dmk could you update the question to correct your intention

Comment: I need search as example I gave. I can't look up with equlity of phrase. I need part of phrase from start of string + part from middle, mayby part from end. Something like regular expression.  In postgres it can be done with % symbol