# Using contains with wildcard in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

After reading then question [How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq) I still have doubts when I need to use wildcard inside the string, like this:

```
%cro%ft%
```

And get results like:

- Microsoft
- Microsoft Corporation
- Acrobat software

For some reason, a simple contains does not works.

### update:

Using .contains(string1) && .contains(string2), give me this sql command:

```
SELECT s."Nome", s."Id", s."Cpf"
  FROM "Pacientes" AS s
 WHERE ((STRPOS(s."Nome", 'cro') > 0) AND (STRPOS(s."Nome", 'ft') > 0))
   AND (s."ClinicaId" = @__clinicId_0)
 ORDER BY s."Nome"
```

instead of a clean sql like:

```
SELECT s."Nome", s."Id", s."Cpf"
  FROM "Pacientes" AS s
 WHERE (s.Nome like '%cro%ft%')
   AND (s."ClinicaId" = @__clinicId_0)
 ORDER BY s."Nome"
```

My code in production is:

```
result = result.Where(s => s.Nome.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));
```

Comment: @Chad That post is tagged as [tag:linq-to-sql]; not the same thing as EF.

Comment: Looks like EF Core 2.1 has [a set of extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctionsExtensions_Like_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_String_System_String_System_String_) you can use.

Comment: @GertArnold, the user type the wildcard, so I don´t know what he will type. Could be %ab%c%de%...

Comment: @KennethK. This could be helpfull. How to use it ?

Comment: Is my change applied: `result.Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(x.Name,"yourWildcardSQLpattern"));`

Comment: @Dongdong, works like a charm.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1040380/1353267 maybe?

Comment: It looks like a bug. It should work similarly to `string.Contains`.