# MySQL Queriable Field Constraint by RegEx

Tags: mysql, regex, information-schema, data-consistency

In addition to a data type of `VARCHAR(255)`, I'd like to add a constraint to the data by a regular expression, e.g. `[a-zA-Z ]`.

I'd like to be able to query the regex, like how I can query meta data in the `information_schema`.

I've seen some related posts, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I've seen: [Restrict varchar() column to specific values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441427/restrict-varchar-column-to-specific-values) which shows how to use constaints, and I've seen via triggers here: [Is it Possible to Enforce Data Checking in MySQL using Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression)

Can RegExs be used as constraints and those constraints be queried? If so, how?

Comment: I got a hackish way of doing it, which would be to put the regex in the column comments then use a trigger to check before insert. I would prefer a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: Not everything can be done in SQL.  This smells like something for the application to do, not a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: True, that is how I've done it in the past, however since the DBE is the handler of the data, I think it makes sense that it helps enforce things. The system I'm working on is also n-tier, so have it controlled at the db level and allowing for the meta data to be queried would allow me to enforce it on various levels. Otherwise its a coordination effort that ends in a lot of work. Going to do a new post to see if any other db engine can do this.

Comment: The following links to the other post I made that opens the question up to all db engines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157662/is-there-a-database-engine-that-allows-for-queriable-field-constraint-specified