# Oracle: How to add constraint to only allow a particular set of numbers in a string column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have a string column, which stores numbers. How can I add a constraint to make sure that the number consists of only `6` or `7`. Example `676666` But I do not want `565677`

Comment: `foo in (6, 7)`  maybe?

Comment: There is not enough information here. Are you talking about a column in a table? A variable in a PL/SQL program? Something else?

Comment: Do you mean you have a column and database where the string length should be 6 or 7 characters only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441427/restrict-varchar-column-to-specific-values

Comment: Oracle SQL, a column in table. it can be like 676666 but not 565677

Comment: is the column type integer or varchar?

Comment: It has to be a string, so varchar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a check constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT check_numbers CHECK (regexp_like(the_column, '^[67]+$'))
```

This requires at last one digit.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. It does not accept this expression.

Comment: @nostress: what do you mean with "does not accept"? Works for me: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c7229678984cd47b957c783379c8a654

Comment: It doesnt accept this expression. it accepts '[67]' but not '^[67]+$'

Comment: Thank you, it was my mistake. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Add this constraint. I didn't run it but please try

```
CONSTRAINT CHECK_6_7_ONLY CHECK (regexp_replace(trim(column_name),'6|7','') is null)
```

Edit: Added `trim` as we are dealing with strings

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [`translate`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions232.htm):

```
create table t42 (
  foo varchar2(10),
  constraint sixesorsevens check (translate(foo, 'x67', 'x') is null)
);

Table T42 created.

insert into t42 (foo) values (null);

1 row inserted.

SQL> insert into t42 (foo) values ('676666');

1 row inserted.

SQL> insert into t42 (foo) values ('576666');

insert into t42 (foo) values ('576666')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (MYSCHEMA.SIXESORSEVENS) violated
```

... but the `regexp_like()` version might be clearer to someone who has to maintain this.