# Restrict a column of any type to specific values?

Tags: sql, oracle

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441427/restrict-varchar-column-to-specific-values), can we use the pattern:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_X CHECK (X IN (...))
```

For any SQL data type? E.g.:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_SomeIntField CHECK (SomeIntField IN (1,2,3,4))
```

Where `SomeIntField` is an `INTEGER`?

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: Also, can't you just try it?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Oracle SQL, and unfortunately I don't have easy access to it at the moment, also for the sake of documentation

Comment: @RobMurray if you have access to a browser, you should be able to use [Oracle's LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com) to do your testing on. It's usually at a recent version of the database.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Also it would take a while to try **all** SQL data types. The general question occured to me while making lots of constraints of this form.

Comment: @Boneist That's great, I'm new to SQL so didn't know about this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this for any data type that supports `IN`.  So it works for strings, numbers, and date/time values.