# How do I perform an accent insensitive compare (e with è, é, ê and ë) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, collation

I'm looking to compare two varchars in SQL, one would be something like `Cafe` and the other `Café` is there a way in SQL that will allow the two values to be compared. For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM Venue
WHERE Name Like '%cafe%'
```

So if there is a venue with the name `Big Bobs Café Extraordinaire` it would be included in the result set?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Coerce to an accent insensitive [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx)

You'll also need to ensure both side have the same collation to avoid errors or further coercions if you want to compare against a table variable or temp table varchar column

<strike>and because the constant value will have the collation of the database Update: only for local variables, not for constants</strike> nope, not even then

```
SELECT *
FROM Venue
WHERE
   Name COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI Like '%cafe%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

Comment: You don't need to provide collation twice in this case: SELECT * FROM Venue WHERE Name Like '%cafe%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI

Comment: I implemented this answer, the search is accent insensitive, but the side effect is that the I am missing some accent in select query. For example c with acute (U+0107).  In column properties I see SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI collation. I changed the collation using following statement: ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN description varchar(48) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI. It used to be Czech_CI_AS collation before. If I use the query in the answer without changing the collation of the column, it is not working in Entity framework.

Answer (score 56):

By applying a specific accent insensitive [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx) to your select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Venue 
WHERE Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI Like '%cafe%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

The CI stands for "Case Insensitive" and AI for "Accent Insensitive".

Comment: Ah, that's what all those silly characters on the end mean. I know it's daft, but that helps a huge amount. Somehow, for me, DB collation always seems to bring brain fog with it.

Comment: Very useful explanation. I could conclude that I need Finnish_Swedish_CI_AI. In swedish we have å, ä and ö as part of the alphabet and my target was variations like é that is not a part of it.

Answer (score 11):

Accent Sensitive and Accent Insensitive searching can be don by using `Latin1_general_CI_AI`

Here `AI` is for Accent Insensitive and `AS` for Accent Sensitive
ie, **Café** and **Cafe** are the same if Accent Insensitive.

In the below query `Latin1_general_CI_AI` can be break down into the following parts.

- `latin1` makes the server treat strings using charset latin 1, basically ascii.
- **CI** specifies case-insensitive, so "ABC" equals to "abc".
- **AI** specifies accent-insensitive,so 'ü' equals to 'u'.

Your **query** should be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Venue WHERE Name COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI Like '%cafe%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

Expected **Result** is as follows:

```
 Id  name
 1  Café
 2  Cafe
```