# How to find names with special characters like 'José' on MS SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008, special-characters

If i search for 'Jose' the result is 0. If i search for 'Josè' either and 'Jôse' gives also no result.

```
select name from TblName where name = 'Jose' or name = 'Josè' or name = 'Jôse'
```

I know the replacement with ? : `where name like 'Jos?' or name like 'J?se'` But this is very unhandy and who knows if there is not a special form of 's'?

I want to search for 'Jose' and get all the variants of it with all the possible special characters on all single characters; how do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See 
[How do I perform an accent insensitive compare (e with è, é, ê and ë) in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-e-e-e-and-e-in-sql-serv)

> By applying a specific [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx)
>   order to your select:
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM Venue 
> WHERE Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI Like '%cafe%'
> ```
>
> The CI stands for "Case Insensitive"
>   and AI for "Accent Insensitive".

If you are French, this article may also help : 
[Remplacer les accents dans une chaîne](http://www.xoowiki.com/Article/Csharp/remplacer-les-accents-dans-une-chaine-373.aspx).

Comment: That is a good solution which i agree, but on huge tables, i think the performance goes south, isn't it?