# Ignoring accents while searching the database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, non-ascii-characters

I have a database table that contains names with accented characters. Like `ä` and so on.

I need to get all records using EF4 from a table that contains some substring *regardless of accents*.

So the following code:

```
myEntities.Items.Where(i => i.Name.Contains("a"));
```

should return all items with a name containing `a`, but also all items containing `ä`, `â` and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: What database are you using? You might have to set a accent-insensitive collation order on that column..

Comment: Can you use this method in EF? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-e-e-e-and-e-in-sql-serv

Comment: @Stuart Dunkeld - That did the trick. I changed the collation for the Name column in the database, and then it worked like a charm. If you post that as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you set an accent-insensitive collation order on the Name column then the queries should work as required.

Comment: How would you change the collation of a specific column by code?

Comment: @AlejandrodelRío see http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/20/sql-server-change-collation-of-database-column-t-sql-script/ for an example

Comment: This can't be done when you already have created the table and it has data inside of it. At least in sql server 2008 R2. When you create a new table or a new database there's no problem at all. My question was about entity framework anyway. Thanks.

Comment: You [can change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx) the column collation as long it is not referenced by a FK, Index, Checks, Computed Column or Distribution statistics. One example of SQL would be `alter table [dbo].[Table] ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] nvarchar(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI;`

Comment: Wouldn't a collation remove the accents upon insertion already?

Comment: @ThomasWeller the collation just affects how the data is queried, it does not modify inserted data - a case insensitive collation does not modify the case of inserted data, after all

Answer (score 11):

Setting an accent-insensitive collation will fix the problem.

You can change the collation for a column in SQL Server and Azure database with the next query.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ALTER COLUMN ColumnName NVARCHAR (100)
COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI NOT NULL
```

`SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI` is the collation where `LATIN1_GENERAL` is English (United States), `CP1` is code page 1252, `CI` is case-insensitive, and  `AI` is accent-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is not so clean solution, but after reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) I tried something like this:

```
var query = this.DataContext.Users.SqlQuery(string.Format("SELECT *  FROM dbo.Users WHERE LastName like '%{0}%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI", parameters.SearchTerm));
```

After that you are still able to call methods on 'query' object like Count, OrderBy, Skip etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an SQL Function to remove the diacritics, by applying to the input string the collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI, like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveDiacritics] (
@input varchar(max)
)   RETURNS varchar(max)

AS BEGIN
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(max);

select @result = @input collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI

return @result
END
```

Then add it in the DB context (in this case ApplicationDbContext) by mapping it with the attribute DbFunction:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomIdentityUser>
    {
        [DbFunction("RemoveDiacritics", "dbo")]
        public static string RemoveDiacritics(string input)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("This method can only be used with LINQ.");
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
}
```

And Use it in LINQ query, for example:

```
var query = await db.Users.Where(a => ApplicationDbContext.RemoveDiacritics(a.Name).Contains(ApplicationDbContext.RemoveDiacritics(filter))).tolListAsync();
```

Answer (score -3):

*Accent-insensitive Collation as Stuart Dunkeld suggested is definitely the best solution ...*

**But maybe good to know:**

Michael Kaplan once posted about stripping diacritics:

```
static string RemoveDiacritics(string stIn)
{
    string stFormD = stIn.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int ich = 0; ich < stFormD.Length; ich++)
    {
        UnicodeCategory uc = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(stFormD[ich]);
        if(uc != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            sb.Append(stFormD[ich]);
        }
    }

    return(sb.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC));
}
```

**[Source](http://www.siao2.com/2007/05/14/2629747.aspx)**

*So your code would be:*

```
myEntities.Items.Where(i => RemoveDiacritics(i.Name).Contains("a"));
```

Comment: Your example will not work because `RemoveDiacritics` will have to run on the SQL server.

Comment: As @Ladislav said, this will strip accent from the *input* string (that will probably already be without accent) and check towards the database that still regards accents. This will actually make it worse, since an input of â will be converted to a, and not even find the â in the database even if the user actually bother to write the accents when performing the search. But.. good to know that there is a way to strip accents of a string in C# should I ever need to do that ;)

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen - I thought your input string would be `"a"`, and `i.Name` the one in the db, but yeah this sould only be one way to strip those if theres more trouble with accents, etc =D