# Entity Framework performs accent sensitive search but direct SQL query performs accent insensitive search

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, azure-sql-database, collation

I have an SQL Azure database which actually has a `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation and when I execute a query using Entity Framework, it does perform an accent sensitive search as expected. However, when I execute a query directly on the server using SSMS, the returned result is accent insensitive. Why would that happen? How can I make Entity Framework LINQ-to-Entites query to also perform an accent insensitive search just like SSMS, without changing the collation?

Comment: What's the default language of SqlServer login You used? What's thread culture you execute your code from?

Comment: @Andrew I haven't specified anything, I don't see anything related to language in database dashboard either. The thread culture is also the default, as I haven't specified anything extra.

Comment: table column, the one you filtered against...does it has it's collation that is accent insensitive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357351/ignoring-accents-while-searching-the-database-using-entity-framework normalization used here can be the solution you are looking for...