# .NET | When I search "crepe" its not returning records that contains "crépe". IQueryable collation search

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is possible to add collation search with IQueryable.

this is my code:

```
public IQueryable<Book> FilterQueryable(IQueryable<Book> queryabable)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Term))
        queryabable = queryabable.Where(c => (c.Name.ToLower().Contains(Keyword.ToLower())));
}
```

My problem is, when I search for eg. "crepe" its not returning records that contains "crépe"

é its ignored.

**EDIT 1**

Text in db is stored `Easy crépe recipe`, this is why I used `contains` (LIKE).

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring accented letters in string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth How is that supposed to translate to SQL?

Comment: Are you using .Net Core or .Net Framework?  The tags are mixed.

Comment: is it stored as `crépe` in the db?

Comment: @Amy sorry, Im using .Net Framework

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth I tried the solution before, it didnt work in my case, I think that solution is when you search 'crépe' to get 'crepe'

Comment: @Train yes, `crépe`  is stored in db

Comment: I would recommend doing this on the DB columns and not in every query of code that has an accent. check the second answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357351/ignoring-accents-while-searching-the-database-using-entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is something that should be done in the DB... Entity Framework simply generates a SQL script, it is the DB engine which does the actual search.

You can use the following script to change your `Name` column:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Book]
ALTER COLUMN Name NVARCHAR (256)
COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI NOT NULL
```