# Search in SQL Server table NVARCHAR column ignoring unicode special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I perform an accent insensitive compare (e with è, é, ê and ë) in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-e-e-e-and-e-in-sql-ser)

Let's say I have in my column text:

```
"some text ... España .. some text"
```

Is it possible to write query which returns me this row even if I write:

```
where dataColumn LIKE N'%espana%'
```

I have limited number of special characters that I have to ignore

thanks for any help

Comment: Depends on your collation - what collation does your database (and this column) have? You can make a collation **accent-sensitive** or **accent-insensitive** ...

Comment: OP: could you spend some time learning how to format your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - it's a wee bit unfair to expect the community to fix them every time you ask a new question. Thanks.