# Replace Azerbaijani characters in string not works correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, replace, collation

When I want to replace Azerbaijani  character 'ş' in my string with 'sh'.it works but it also replaces 's' with 'sh'

How can i solve it .Any ideas?

```
REPLACE(mystring,'ş','sh')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409462/compare-s-t-with-%C5%9F-%C5%A3-in-sql-server

Comment: it is not answer .Different question.Please read question

Answer (score 1):

The character "ş" belongs to Turkish_CI_AS. It is a problem inserting them to database and retreiving them too. The trick is to use nvarchar and use N while inserting and querying.

Refer to the example below.

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'arshad khan earns 1000ş',N'ş','sh');

SELECT 'ş'

SELECT N'ş'
```

Output is as below

arshad khan earns 1000sh

s

ş

Comment: This is result of your query

"arshhad khan earnsh 1000sh" . it replace 's' also with 'sh' .my column is nvarchar no need to put N in the head .so problem is not about putting N

Comment: what is your database collation ?

Answer (score 0):

This character is represented as Unicode

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9E

Use this article, to solve your problem

[how to insert unicode text to SQL Server from query window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350968/how-to-insert-unicode-text-to-sql-server-from-query-window)

Regards
R

Comment: Read question please.do not answer just for getting grade.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution after research.

It happens in two characters 'ş' and 'ç' if you want to replace these characters with something else it will also replace 's' and 'c'.

Of course if your database collation is 'Turkish_CI_AS' it will work .But in my case only for two characters i could not change my database collation.No logic in it.

so my client just wanted from me change Azeri characters to latin 'ş'->'s'.

My solution when i start i replace 's' with special character  and put it back after i replace all azeri characters to latin.so my original 'c' and 's' characters not effected after replacement.

This is a function I wrote

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[funRGMReplaceAzeriCharacters] 
(           
    @string nvarchar (MAX)
)  
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS  
BEGIN 

DECLARE 
    @Result nvarchar(MAX)
    Begin 

    SET @Result=REPLACE(@string,'s' ,'V1986Q')

    SET @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'c' ,'V1987Q')

    SET @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'ı' ,'i')

    SET @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'ə','a')

    SET @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'ğ','g')

    SET @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'ü','u')

    SET @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'ş','sh')

    SET @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'ç','ch')

    Set @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'ö','o')

    -- bring back s and c

    Set @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'V1986Q','s')

    Set @Result=REPLACE(@Result,'V1987Q','c')
    END    
   RETURN UPPER (@Result)
END
```