# ignore accents on search using linq to entities (EF)

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

i need to perform a search on over a table whit a string field that contains accents (á, ì, ü, etc) im using EF 6

first i try i direct search like:

```
 var listaResultados = db_hms.Topology
                .Where( t => t.is_active == true && ((t.display_name.Contains(busqueda))||(t.detail.Contains(busqueda))))
```

but this is accent sensitive, then i try this:

```
t.display_name.IndexOf(busqueda, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

but is not supported on linq to Entities

any other idea please 
pd: i need to perform the search on a "Contains" way, not a starts whit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These comparisons will depend on collation you selected when creating your SQL Server Database. I don't know if the EF has any workarounds but you can possibly get around this using a stored procedure to invoke something along the lines of this:

[How do I perform an accent insensitive compare (e with è, é, ê and ë) in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-e-e-e-and-e-in-sql-ser)

Comment: so far i haven't been able to find a workaround on EF, so im changing the collations on the specific fields i need to perform a search, the problem is that now i need validation over unique fields