# How to filter record with duplicated characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to filter records by if it is contain duplicated characters:

I have a T-SQL statement that filters record for my needs:

```
select * 
from Table 
where WordValue not like '%[^çam]%'
  and len(WordValue) <= 3
order by len(WordValue)
```

Results:

[image]

As normally, you can see in the `WordValue` column contains records with "**aa**" and "**aça**", but I would like to filter record if it contains multiple same character.

Thanks advance.

Comment: you wants to filter 'aa' as well?

Comment: Not only aa, if it has duplicate character, each record these have duplicated characters

Comment: What counts as a duplicated character? Is `A` a duplicate of `a`? Is `c` a duplicate of `ç`? Does `ß` count as a duplicate on it's own as it represents `ss`?

Comment: A = a, c = c, ç = ç  etc.

Comment: Define a Case Insensitive, Accent Insensitive Collation Set for your string comparison : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-%C3%A8-%C3%A9-%C3%AA-and-%C3%AB-in-sql-ser Don't use Latin1_General but the collation set corresponding to your own language https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way in SQL Server to handle this is to count each character:

```
where len(replace(wordvalue) - len(replace(wordvalue, 'a', ''))) <= 1 and
      len(replace(wordvalue) - len(replace(wordvalue, 'm', ''))) <= 1 and
      len(replace(wordvalue) - len(replace(wordvalue, 'ç', ''))) <= 1 and
      WordValue not like '%[^çam]%' and
      len(WordValue) <= 3
```

Or:

```
where wordvalue not like '%a%a%' and
      wordvalue not like '%m%m%' and
      wordvalue not like '%ç%ç%' and
      WordValue not like '%[^çam]%' and
      len(WordValue) <= 3
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8da7d325d0c165951888900a3babab9c) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

I interpreted the question as filtering OUT values.  If you only want values with duplicates, then just invert the conditions:

```
where (wordvalue like '%a%a%' and
       wordvalue like '%m%m%' or
       wordvalue like '%ç%ç%'
      ) and
      WordValue not like '%[^çam]%' and
      len(WordValue) <= 3
```

Comment: Why I need this if i can resolve it like '%[^çam^]%'

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu . . . Because this answer does what you are asking for and that does not.  I've included a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

I just find a solution, if it is best practice:

```
select * from Words where 
WordValue NOT LIKE '%[^çam^]%'
and NotExist = 0 
and len(WordValue) <= 3
```

Changed query from **'%[^çam]%'** to **'%[^çam^]%'**

**Results:**
[image]

Comment: I don't se how this filters out "aa".

Comment: Results doenst have the AA record. Look carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
select wordcontaindubles from Table where wordcontaindubles like ('%' + 'aa' + '%')
select TurkishLanguage from Table where TurkishLanguage like ('%' + 'çam' + '%')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).