# Search string against "%"

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to write a c# search function that supports "%" in SQL like operator in searching.
For eg,

"%m%" will match all strings like below.

- some
- me
- sum
- etc..

"%m%e" will match strings something like "some".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static bool Like(string expression, string value)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(value, "^" + 
        Regex.Escape(expression).Replace("%", @"[\s\S]*?") + "$", 
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Good catch using `Regex.Escape` to prevent invalid regex patterns.

Comment: +1 I was writing "it's perfect. The first regex written correctly (and perfectly" in one shot (a record) ). But then I noticed you didn't anchor it :-) The string `Hello` will match `Hello World` :-)

Comment: @Rubens: you've forgot about LIKE's escape character `!`. :) You need a "real" parser.

Comment: @Ruben, How can I make it case insensitive??

Comment: @RubensFarias `var result = Like("Hello", "Hello World"); // Should be false, it's true`

Comment: @Kai, using `RegexOptions` you can control case sensitivity. Updated

Answer (score 3):

```
public bool SqlWildcardMatch(string input, string sqlLikePattern)
{
     sqlLikePattern = Regex.Replace(sqlLikePattern, "^([^%])", "^$1");
     sqlLikePattern = Regex.Replace(sqlLikePattern, "([^%])$", "$1$$");

     return Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Replace(sqlLikePattern, "%", ".*"));
}
```

This function will likely need refining to ensure `sqlLikePattern` doesn't produce an invalid regex pattern, but consider it a starting point.

Comment: Thanks..I think it is what I'm looking for.Let me try.

Comment: beware with `sqlLikePattern` with regex characters; you must sanitize them first

Comment: And you have to translate `_` as `.`. And you need to support LIKE's escape character `!`.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to have the way SQL's `LIKE` treats underscores, you could use my answer to [C# Version Of SQL LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417070/c-sharp-version-of-sql-like/5419544#5419544) and if not, you could remove the bit `Replace('_', '.')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could realize that using regular expressions.

Please have a look at:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/wildcardtoregex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

what about using [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) `.*m.*`