# Lambda expression "Likes" Operator available?

Tags: c#, lambda

I m building dynamic lambda expression.I got the following operators working for this code "Contains","StartsWith","EndsWith".

**Source code**

```
var method = typeof(string).GetMethod(opType.ToString(), new[] { typeof(string) }); 
var startsWithDishExpr = Expression.Call(argLeft, method, argRight);
```

But **Like** operator didnt work. 
I tried this code for "Like" Operator

```
var likeExpression = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods), "Like", null, argLeft, argRight);
```

Anyone have answer for this? Please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods`, so you have to create a `Like` method yourself .

---

**Example:**

```
void Main()
{
    var argLeft = Expression.Constant("Foobar", typeof(string));
    var argRight = Expression.Constant("F%b%r", typeof(string));

    var likeExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(StringHelper), "Like", null, argLeft, argRight);

    Expression.Lambda(likeExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke().Dump();
}
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static bool Like(string toSearch, string toFind)
    {
        return new Regex(@"\A" + new Regex(@"\.|\$|\^|\{|\[|\(|\||\)|\*|\+|\?|\\").Replace(toFind, ch => @"\" + ch)
                                                                                  .Replace('_', '.')
                                                                                  .Replace("%", ".*") + @"\z", 
                         RegexOptions.Singleline).IsMatch(toSearch);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> True

(example implementation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419544/142637))

---

**EDIT:**

Since you are using Entity Framework, you should use [`PatIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx) instead.

```
var likeExpression = Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Call(typeof(SqlFunctions), "PatIndex", null, argLeft, argRight),
                                            Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int?)));
```

Comment: Steak, I m getting this exception                                      base {System.Exception} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}                                                        source code                                                                var likeExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(StringHelper), "Like", null, argLeft, argRight);
return likeExpression;

Comment: Ah, your using LINQ to Entities. I'm afraid using a custom method will not work then.

Comment: @sivaL I updated my anser to show how to use `PatIndex`, which will work like `Like` (but SQL Server only).

Comment: Steak, I tried this PatIndex, It generated expression like this ..Company => (PatIndex(Company.Name, "test%") > 0).  It should return the results with All starts with test. But it dint return anything. But It has - starts with "test" many records. It worked only for this query.. Company => (PatIndex(Company.Name, "test") > 0). Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Steak, It was my mistake , It should be like this               Company => (PatIndex("test%",Company.Name ) >0). Interchanged left and right. Its working great. Thanks a lot Steak

Answer (score 1):

I believe SqlMethods.Like is supported

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx

if not use a lambda expression

list.exists(element => element.Contains("your search string");