# How to use Like operator in entity framework lamba expression

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, entity-framework-4

I am writing an sql query for search where the users searches according to the FirstName and LastName. The query works fine when searched for FirstName or LastName, but when I search for FirstName and LastName(ie space between FirstName and LastName), it gives out blank result. The query string looks like this:
 `http://localhost:4562/api/User/Search?q=sumedha%20v&filters=&offset=3&limit=9`

The sql query is : `List<AppUser> searchedAppUsers =  await _context.AppUser.Where(u => u.Profile.FirstName.StartsWith(q) || u.Profile.LastName.StartsWith(q)).ToListAsync();`

I tried using `Contains()` instead of `StartsWith()` but it still gives a blank result. I also tried using `SqlMethods.Like()` but couldn't see it in the intellisense. I tried using `SqlFunctions.PatIndex()`, but same problem. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457586/lambda-expression-likes-operator-available) post, but dint get how to do it.
Is there any other way? or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Try to use this query:
`var searchedAppUsers =  await _context.AppUser.Where(u => u.Profile.FirstName.ToLowerCase().Contains(q.ToLowerCase()) || u.Profile.FirstName.ToLowerCase().Contains(q.ToLowerCase())).ToListAsync();`. Maybe you have query and data in different cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if your search term is "sumedha v" it's obvious that there's no `FirstName` or `LastName` that contains this string. You're apparently looking for something like this:

```
_context.AppUser
        .Where(u => (u.Profile.FirstName + " " + u.Profile.LastName).Contains(q))
```

But this may perform poorly, because now the query engine can't use any index on the name fields. It shouldn't be a problem if there aren't many (thousands of) users.

Maybe you meant to do a search on `FirstName` and `LastName` using the first and second part of the search string respectively? Like this:

```
var parts = q.Split(q, ' ');
var q1 = parts[0];
var q2 = parts[1];
var result = _context.AppUser
                     .Where(u => u.Profile.FirstName.Contains(q1)
                         && u.Profile.LastName.Contains(q2));
```

(without null checks)

This would perform better, because the names fields are queried directly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes this works. All I did was  `   _context.AppUser
                   .Where(u => u.Profile.FirstName + " " + u.Profile.LastName).Contains(q)` without actually including the `Split` part, it gives the as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your query only checks FirstName:

List searchedAppUsers =  await _context.AppUser.Where(u => u.Profile.**FirstName**.StartsWith(q) || u.Profile.**FirstName**.StartsWith(q)).ToListAsync();

Secondly as I understand it you are searching for something like "John Doe" but neither FirstName ("John") nor LastName ("Doe") starts with "John Doe" (or is **LIKE 'John Doe%'**).

Think again about what your SQL would be.

Comment: O made a mistake in posting the question. I have updated the question. The query does checks the LastName as well.