# Replace character with any possible string c#

Tags: c#, string, replace

Lets say i have string like this `Test%Test` and i have stored strings like this:

`Test123Test
TestTTTTest
Test153jhdsTest
123Test
TEST123`

So what i want is when i type in textbox `Test` it would filter me everything with `Test` in itselft and that will get me all strings which is easy, but i want to type in `Test%Test` and it needs to filter me everything that has `Test[anything]Test` in itself (so result would be first, second and third string). How can i do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417070/c-sharp-version-of-sql-like link can help you.

Comment: There is probably a good regex for it. But I'm by no means a regex expert. So I would solve it with String.StartsWith  and String.EndsWith. So spiltting the seach term on '%' and than using to two values

Comment: What is the role of the `%` character here? Is it some sort of wildcard? A separator? Or is it a literal "%"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple solution using a regex is:

```
string[] values = new string[] { "Test123Test",
            "TestTTTTest",
            "Test153jhdsTest",
            "123Test",
            "TEST123" };

string searchQuery = "Test%Test";

string regex = Regex.Escape(searchQuery).Replace("%", ".*?");

string[] filteredValues = values.Where(str => Regex.IsMatch(str, regex)).ToArray();
```

Or for a single match:

```
string value = "Test123Test";

string searchQuery = "Test%Test";

string regex = Regex.Escape(searchQuery).Replace("%", ".*?");

if ( Regex.IsMatch(value, regex) )
{
    // do something with the match...                
}
```

We replace % with a regular expression (. = any character, * = zero or more times, ? = lazy quantifier). You can learn more about regular expressions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx)