# Like operator in SQL alternative in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check if any string entered after a certain message I do have a working version in SQL that I want to use almost the same one in C#

Usage in SQL:

```
        ELSE IF @Msg LIKE '/Message %'
```

Usage in C#:

```
        else if (Msg == "/Message ")
```

I want the tool to check if any string entered right after /Message.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Version Of SQL LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417070/c-sharp-version-of-sql-like)

Comment: I don't want to search for a string in a string. I want to read any possible string entered

Comment: Are you already familiar with `string.StartsWith()`, `string.Contains()` and `string.EndsWith()`?

Comment: I'm not understanding how the two questions differ.  You want to test if `Msg` contains `"/Message "` followed by arbitrary text, and optionally retrieve and act on that arbitrary text?  The linked question, as well as [the many other duplicates or near-duplicates](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+c%23+like+operator), provide the building blocks for how to do that.  It might be better to look at this through the lens of regular expressions, not SQL, as that is what the solution will likely involve (if not the basic `string` methods @RufusL notes).

Comment: Which specific LIKE features do you need? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql . I assume you need % but do you need _ support? [] support? [^] support? etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the TSQL LIKE keyword works.

---

```
using System;

namespace SqlLike
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var findMe = "ABCHelloXYZ";

            // LIKE '......%'
            if (findMe.StartsWith("ABC"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yay");
            }

            // LIKE '%......'
            if (findMe.EndsWith("XYZ"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Woohoo");
            }

            // LIKE '%......%'
            if (findMe.Contains("Hello"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("JackPot!!");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your commented out lines are backwards. `findMe.StartsWith("....")` is the same thing as `LIKE '....%'` and `findMe.EndsWith("....")` is the same thing as `LIKE '%....'`

Comment: `"#Hello%";` Shouldn't that be `"%Hello%";`?

Comment: @mjwills I shouldn't have used % as an example. I've updated to better illustrate what I meant.

Comment: What if "aaa%bbb%ccc%ddd"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following `string` functions:

```
var Msg = "A message to check";
```

For `LIKE 'SomeText%'`:

```
if (Msg.StartsWith("SomeText"))
```

For `LIKE '%SomeText'`:

```
if (Msg.EndsWith("SomeText"))
```

For `LIKE '%SomeText%'`:

```
if (Msg.Contains("SomeText"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a little vague, but this should get you there (with a little adjustment as needed).

```
String Msg = "/Message somethingelse";
        if (Msg.Contains("/Message ") && (Msg.Length > 9) )
        {
            String str = Msg.Substring(9);
            Console.Write("str: " + str);
        }
```

As @Scott suggested you can also use:

```
if (Msg.StartsWith("/Message ") && (Msg.Length > 9))
        {
            String str = Msg.Substring(9);
            Console.Write("str: " + str);
        }
```

Comment: That will also match strings that have text *before* `"/Message"`

Comment: Yes as I said the requirements are a little vague but hopefully enough to get Crepitus going

Comment: The requirement is to make code that acts like `@Msg LIKE '/Message %'`, your example acts like `@Msg LIKE '%/Message %'`. You need a `StartsWith` instead of a `Contains`

Comment: also the sql submitted indicates that the string will always start with "/Message"

Comment: thanks  @Scott Chamberlain  I will add your suggestion to the answer

Comment: Well, we don't see what the value of `Msg` is, but he wants to test if it starts with `/Message`