# Contains: Get a specific word in a specific starting/ending point

Tags: c#, winforms, contains

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417070/c-sharp-version-of-sql-like), however, I would like to do this without having to create any extra separated function, is it possible?

What do I have:

- *Load_*XXXX.5gpl_TempCycle
- RO_Mass_*Load_*XXXX.AAAA-31974-B
- RO_Mass*_Load_*XXXX.AAAA-31980
- RO_Mass_Load_Test_4a-B_TempCycle_20170427-41309
- Load_Test_4a_TempCycle

I wanna take out:

- only the ones that start with "Load_".
- or finishes with "-B"

Problem:
If I use Contains(string), it will take out all of them.

What do I need:
A Contain (or something else?) that takes out strings that start with "Load_" or finishes with "-B".

Result expect:

- RO_Mass*_Load_*XXXX.AAAA-31980
- RO_Mass_Load_Test_4a-B_UUU_20170427-41309

Code not working(it gets everything out):

```
if (item.Full_File_Name.Contains("-B") || item.Full_File_Name.Contains("Load"))
```

Any ideas or help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have prepared functions for that: `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`

```
if (item.Full_File_Name.EndsWith("-B") || item.Full_File_Name.StartsWith("Load"))
```

If we want one *or* the other, we should use:

```
if (!item.Full_File_Name.EndsWith("-B") && !item.Full_File_Name.StartsWith("Load_"))
```

Comment: Wow, that was juvenile from my part. Thank you!

Comment: @Fabio Soares will it serve your purpose?  I think it will also return those ones who starts with Load as well which is different from your Expected Result.

Comment: @Ramankingdom, for my case it will work... I was trying to eliminate Load_... or ...-B; If B or Load are in the middle, I don't care. During my tests, it works.

Comment: @Ramankingdom, you are right! The correct should be: if (!item.Full_File_Name.EndsWith("-B") && !item.Full_File_Name.StartsWith("Load_"))