# Get SQL LINQ Results Based off of String List

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Lets start off with a list of strings that will be used to filter the results:

```
 List<String> RadioNames = new List<String>();
 RadioNames.AddRange(new String[] { "abc", "123", "cba", "321" });
```

I want to be able to filter a LINQ to SQL database table based on `RadioNames` but the catch is that I want `RadioNames` to be a partial match (meaning it will catch Radio123 and not just 123).

The source that I need to filter is below:

```
var ChannelGrants = from cg in sddc.ChannelGrants
                    select new
                    {
                        cg.ID,
                        cg.Timestamp,
                        cg.RadioID,
                        cg.Radio
                    };
```

So I need to perform something similar to below (outside of the original `ChannelGrants` results as this is a conditional search)

```
 if(RadioNamesToSearch != null)
 {
      List<String> RadioNames = new List<String>();

      // Here I split all the radio names from RadioNamesToSearch based on a command separator and then populate RadioNames with the results

      ChannelGrants = from cg in ChannelGrants
                      where ???
                      select cg;
 }
```

I need help where  ??? is in the code above (or if `ChannelGrants = ...` is invalid all together). Repeating above, I need to filter `ChannelGrants` to return any matches from `RadioNames` but it will do partial matches (meaning it will catch Radio123 and not just 123).

All the code is contained in a method as such...

```
 public static DataTable getBrowseChannelGrants(int Count = 300, String StartDate = null, String StartTime = null, String EndDate = null, String EndTime = null, String RadioIDs = null, String RadioNamesToSearch = null, String TalkgroupIDs = null, String TalkgroupNames = null, bool SortAsc = false)
```

Comment: What is the difference between `RadioNames` and `RadioNamesToSearch`? Where does the latter come from? You haven't declared it anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post to show the method the code is contained in. I left out most of the 270 lines of code to help readability.

Comment: @seekerOfKnowledge Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, there doesn't seem to be a best way so I'll answer this until a new answer that doesn't repeat the other answers that don't work on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

in place of the ???

```
RadioNames.Where(rn=>cg.Radio.ToLower().Contains(rn.ToLower())).Count() > 0
```

That should do it...

The ToLower() calls are optional, of course.

EDIT: I just wrote this and it worked fine for me in a Console Application. The result contained one item and the WriteLine spit out "cbaKentucky". Not sure what to tell ya.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> RadioNames = new List<String>();
        RadioNames.AddRange(new String[] { "abc", "123", "cba", "321" });

        List<ChannelGrants> grants = new List<ChannelGrants>();
        grants.Add(new ChannelGrants() { ID = 1, Radio = "cbaKentucky", RadioID = 1, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now });

        var result = from cg in grants
                  where RadioNames.Where(rn=>cg.Radio.ToLower().Contains(rn.ToLower())).Count() > 0
                  select cg;

        foreach (ChannelGrants s in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Radio);
        }
    }
}

class ChannelGrants
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public int RadioID { get; set; }
    public string Radio { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code - Message=Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Comment: The code I was using was: `where filterRadioNames.Where(frn => cg.Radio.Name.ToLower().Contains(frn.ToLower())).Count() > 0`

Answer (score 0):

What field in ChannelGrants are you comparing RadioNames to?

To retrieve entries that are only in your RadioNames list, you'd use the contains method like this

```
ChannelGrants = from cg in ChannelGrants
                  where RadioNames.Contains(cg.Radio)
                  select cg;
```

(If you wanted to find all rows that had one of your RadioNames in the Radio property.  Replace cg.Radio with the appropriate column you are matching)

This gives you a similar outcome if you had this where clause in SQL

```
where cg.Radio in ("abc", "123", "cba", "321")
```

from this link [How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)
it looks like you can combo it with like matching as well, but adding slashes, by it's not something I've done personally.

Comment: Sorry, the field `cg.Radio.Name` matched with the list `RadioNames` - I'll try out this code now.

Comment: I had no choice but to translate what you had to `where RadioNames.Any(frn => cg.Radio.Name.ToLower().Contains(frn.ToLower()))` because I'm looking to see if any `RadioNames` are contained in the cg.Radio.Name property. I got the error "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."