# How can I write a linq statement for LIKE in sql

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, sql-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)

I am trying to implement the code below in LINQ, but still I couldn't find a way:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE City LIKE '%tav%'
```

How can I write this in LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var query = dataContext.Person.Where(p=>p.City.Contains("tav"));
```

Depending on your sql server configuration you may need to compare only lower-case or upper-case letters:

```
var query = dataContext.Person.Where(p=>p.City.ToLower().Contains("tav"));
```