# Linq 1 letter search and search with numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
var search = (from c in db.**
                          where c.first_name == txtbox.Text || Convert.ToInt32(c.id = txtbox.Text)
                          select new
                          {
                              ID = c.ID,
                              FullName = c.name,
                              FirstName = c.first,
                              LastName = c.last
                          });
```

I am trying to use a textbox to search database for the name if the name is entered or if they decide to use an ID then search by the ID. When I try it sees that a letter is being used and it's trying to find a number.

Also I would like it so say I enter "A" into the textbox I would like to search for everyone that has an "A" in their name.

Any help would be awesome thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var searchText = txtbox.Text.Trim();
var searchForId = false;
int id;
if(int.TryParse(searchText, out id)){
    searchForId = true;
}

var search = (from c in db.**
    where 
        c.first_name.Contains(searchText) 
        || searchForId && c.id == id
    select new
    {
        ID = c.ID,
        FullName = c.name,
        FirstName = c.first,
        LastName = c.last
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Didn't know about the "Contains"

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is contains not equal found this i hope it helps [How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq).