# Linq contains for SQL Like %

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Basically I'd like to use a LINQ statement for an sql like %. I thought .Contains would be appropriate but I don't get the right result.

I have a model:

```
public class Model {
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Inside my function:

```
private List<Model> getSearchResults(List<Model> models) 
{
    List<Model> result = models.Where(m => m.Number.Contains("3330")).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Inside my models list is definitively an entry with number 3330, but the returned result is empty. :(
This should also work with .Contains("333"). But it doesn't.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. We don't know enough about the types involved to help you yet. The `Contains` method certainly *does* work, so the problem is likely to be how you're using it. Note that if `l.Number` is just a string, then you're not using the LINQ `Contains` method at all, but the `String.Contains` method.)

Comment: List is from type List and is filled with content from my database. Number is a string.

Comment: That doesn't really help us (partly because your comment may have included generic types but without using a backtick to quote, thus losing the types from what we can see). Please edit your post with a short but complete example.

Comment: One thing i don't understand here. Why do u want to use contains for matching a single value. Contains is an equivalent to sql 'IN'. I don't think its appropriate using it here.

Comment: I thought contains is the same as LIKE.
In sql it would be: SELECT * FROM table WHERE number LIKE '%3330%'. So it will find the entry with number '3330', 'A3330', '3330Z' etc.

Comment: @mosquito87 `Contains` most definitely works, look at this [sample code](https://ideone.com/o3guqK). The problem is with your logic or how you are using it.

Comment: @mosquito87 NO Contains is an equivalent for IN. I have shared the link in answer. Plz check.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're actually using the linq-to-sql provider.
If that's the case, then you should use [`SqlMethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
list.Where(l => SqlMethods.Like(l.Number, "%12%")).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not using the linq-to-sql provider. Sorry.

Comment: -1 What makes you suspect that? There is absolutely no mention of L2S nor does the OP mention any sort of exception using `Contains` (which I am *pretty* sure L2S throws). This is guesswork.

Comment: @James An educated guess though. The OP did mention that the list contains data retrieved from the database, in the comments. And since L2S doesn't support `String.Contains`, this seemed like the case. It was a fair assumption to make, in my opinion. Tbh, I had no idea whether an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Contains statements should be used like sql operator 'IN'. See the link for details:

[tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx)

I think you are looking for something like this:

[how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)

You should use like this:

```
List<Model> result = models.Where(m => m.Number.Contains("/3330/")).ToList();
```

You can also use .StartsWith() or .EndsWith()

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same thing as provided in your second link, right?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But this is definitively not working! The solution you posted is for finding entries with "/3330/", but I'm looking for "3330". The original author had to use "/12/", as he was looking for a month!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my sample of code for you issue, and yes, the Contains method certainly does work:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class Model {
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    private static List<Model> getSearchResults(List<Model> models) 
    {
        List<Model> result = models.Where(m => m.Number.Contains("3330")).ToList();

        return result;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Model> list = new List<Model>() {
            new Model() { Number = "13330A"},
            new Model() { Number = "13230A"},
            new Model() { Number = "3330A"},
            new Model() { Number = "543330"},
            new Model() { Number = "48913"},
            new Model() { Number = "97798133"},
            new Model() { Number = "542130"}
        };

        foreach(Model v in getSearchResults(list)) {
            Console.WriteLine(v.Number);
        }      
    }
}
```

and output is:

```
13330A
3330A
543330
```

Check your code, you can play with this example on http://dotnetfiddle.net/143UgC