# %".search."% in C#

Tags: c#, sql, search, equals

I have this code to select a row from DGV.

```
if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
{
    row.Selected = true;
    break;
}
```

Is there anything like

`%".$searchvalue."%`

from sql to use in C#, so it would found seemingly entrances not only exactly ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string.Contains instead of Equals

```
if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
{
    row.Selected = true;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gilad!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out only the `entrances` of the string you can use `StartsWith` like below.

```
if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().StartsWith(searchValue))
{
    row.Selected = true;
    break;
}
```

If you want to find out only the `endings` of the string you can use `EndsWith` like below.

```
if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().EndsWith(searchValue))
{
    row.Selected = true;
    break;
}
```

You can use `contains` in the above cases if you are not so worried about the performance.

Comment: StartsWith  will only look for first cahracters of first word or will it look for first characters of any word ?

And what would be the performance impact if I use contains?

Comment: It looks for only first characters  of the first word. `Contains` uses a different algorithm and it needs to compute more combinations than `StartsWith` or `EndsWith`. Hence it is used for the cases where we dont know where our required string matcher lies.  If you are so sure about what you need to search and it comes up in the begining or ending then you can use these. Otherwise `Contains` is not a bad choice.

Comment: If you want to check first characters of every word then you need to split the string by `space` and loop through each piece to check whether it startswith `matching string` or not.

Answer (score 0):

In *general case*, if you want to *mimic* sql `LIKE` construction you can try *regular expressions*:

```
public static bool Like(String value, String like) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(like) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return false; // or throw exception

  String pattern = "^" + Regex.Escape(like).Replace("%", ".*").Replace("_", ".") + "$";

  return Regex.IsMatch(value, pattern);
}
```

....

```
String source = "abcdef";
// true
bool result = Like(source, "%b_d%");
```

In your case

```
if (Like(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), searchValue)) { ... }
```