# How to use List items as keyword to compare it to string?

Tags: c#, linq

For example the list `lstHazProduct` contains items like `"NOTEBOOK LAPTOP", "MOBILE PHONE"`.

```
strTest = "SAMSUNG NOTEBOOK";
```

How to use `linq` or `%LIKE%` operator.

If the list items exist in the string, then condition met. Below doesn't work as it compare the string to the list items.

```
if (lstHazProducts.Where(s => s.HazpName.Contains(strTest)).Count() > 0)
{
 //do something
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you use `%LIKE% `, then no items in `lstHazProduct` contains `strTest`

Comment: Try Substring() method on string class. EDIT: %LIKE% is more of SQL syntax.

Comment: May be try to split strings and look in the splits for meeting words?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045735/2772050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is enough to check for matching items of `lstHazProducts` with `strTest` similar to `%Like%`. But that is not enough to perform a search for check for items in the list that contains any words in the `strTest`.
You can use the following code in that case:

```
var searchParams = strTest.Split(' ');
if (lstHazProducts.Count(s => searchParams.Any(s.HazpName.Contains)) > 0)
{
   //do something
}
```

As an alternative for `Count()>0` you can try `Any()` like the following:

```
if (lstHazProducts.Any(s => searchParams.Any(s.HazpName.Contains)))
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: @Toshi: thanks your sporting the error. S.Petrosov Thanks for the edit as well. Have few more updates

Comment: @Toshi: Why are you performing the split on `strTest` for all items in the `lstHazProducts`?

Comment: @Toshi: Yep, that would be a nice option, let me update

Comment: @JonathanLim: Mark it as accepted if it really usefull

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's agree with condiotion(s). So far, so good you have

```
string strTest = "SAMSUNG NOTEBOOK";
```

It seems that you what to check if any *word* (`SAMSUNG`, `NOTEBOOK`) is in the string, if it's your case:

```
// In case strTest is long, HashSet<T> is the most efficient structure  
HashSet<String> terms = new HashSet<String>(strTest.Split(
    new char[] { ' ' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), // to prevent double space false positive
  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);        // let be nice and allow "NoteBook"

...

List<String> lstHazProduct = new List<String>() {
  "NOTEBOOK LAPTOP", 
  "MOBILE PHONE", 
};

var result = lstHazProduct
  .Where(line => line
     .Split(new char[] { ' ' })
     .Any(item => terms.Contains(item)))
  .ToArray(); // let's materialize the result into an array
```