# How can I search for a range of characters using Linq2Sql?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to incorporate the LINQ equivalent of this SQL query.
The database is SQL Server.

```
SELECT * FROM Party
WHERE Partyname LIKE '[a-m]%z'
```

This query will return all the records where the partyname column can start with any letter between a - m and must end with the letter z.

If I wanted to do a LINQ equivalent, how can I do this?
I tried to do this in this fashion, but clearly there is a better way.

```
Parties.Where(p => (p.Partyname.StartsWith("a") || p.Partyname.StartsWith("b") ||
p.Partyname.StartsWith("c")) && p.Partyname.EndsWith("Z"))
.Select(x => new { x.Party_id, x.Partyname, x.Party_no, x.Reference, x.Input_dt })
```

*Note: Linqpad pluralizes the name of the table.*

Comment: Check out the top comment from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045735

Comment: How can I use the SqlMethods helper class in the method syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use combine between linq and regular

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex searchTerm =  
        new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"Visual (Basic|C#|C\+\+|Studio)");  

var queryMatchingFiles =  
        from file in fileList  
        where file.Extension == ".htm"  
        let fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.FullName)  
        let matches = searchTerm.Matches(fileText)  
        where matches.Count > 0  
        select new  
        {  
            name = file.FullName,  
            matchedValues = from System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches  
                            select match.Value  
        };
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-combine-linq-queries-with-regular-expressions