# Multiple like in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a string[] variable which i want to use in the lambda expression to filter data using **like** clause. I tried using **contains**, but it works like the **'in'** clause, which is not what I need.

Please see the code below which behaves like **in** clause:

```
var inventories = ..............AsQuerable();
string[] strArray = <<somevalues>>;
inventories = inventories.Where(c => !strArray.Contains(c.columnName));
```

Could someone provide me the lambda expression which could filter records using **like** instead of **in** using an array.

Comment: It's not clear which string you want to match with `LIKE`. The way you use `Contains` isn't anywhere near `LIKE`. It's an exact match.

Comment: Are you trying the like condition for every value in strArray? e.g. c.columnName = 'lorem ipsum'. strArray = {'a', 'l', 'p'}. Now, you want to match c.columnName with each value of strArray. And if it matches with anyone of them, then pick that value. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike VB.NET, C# has no builtin *like*-operator. However, you can use the operator from VB.NET easily. What you have to do is to reference the assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and include a `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;` at the top of your file. Then you can do

```
 var inventories = ..............AsQuerable();
 string[] strArray = <<somevalues>>;
 inventories = inventories.Where(c => !strArray.Any(s => LikeOperator.LikeString(c.columnName, s, CompareMethod.Text)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The only methods LINQ provide for this purpose is `.Where()`, `.StartsWith()` or `.EndsWith().`. Also, there is pretty similar question here [How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I think this is what you are trying to accomplish. If not, please provide some more information and I will update my answer.

To check if a string is equal to a part of another string (which **like** does), you can use the `.Contains` method:

```
bool contains = "Some fancy sentence".Contains("fancy");
```

This will evaluate to true. Given your example, this would result in the following:

```
var inventories = ..............AsQuerable();
string[] strArray = <<somevalues>>;
inventories = inventories.Where(inv => !strArray.Any(s => inv.columnName.Contains(s)));
```

This checks all inventories and removes all inventories where the inventory column name (partially) occurs in any of the `strArray` values.

Answer (score 0):

It is not pure `Lambda` expression, but Maybe it can help:

```
List<SomeObject> inventories = new List<SomeObject>();
// add objects to list...
string[] strArray = <<somevalues>>;
// result will be stored here
List<SomeObject> filtered = new List<SomeObject>();

foreach (var itm in strArray)
{
    // LIKE '%SOMEVALUE%'
    var match = inventories.Where(x => x.columnName.Contains(itm)).ToList();
    // LIKE '%SOMEVALUE'
    // var match = inventories.Where(x => x.columnName.StartsWith(itm)).ToList();
    // LIKE 'SOMEVALUE%'
    // var match = inventories.Where(x => x.columnName.EndsWith(itm)).ToList();
    foreach (var m in match)
        filtered.Add(m);
}
```